# Need help on understand a question on inverse functions

Tags: calculus, inverse-function

I need help understanding what this question is asking and I am not sure what to do. The question is given below

> For each number y find the maximum value of $yx - 2x^4$. This maximum is a function $G(y)$. Verify that the derivative $G(y)$ and $2x^4$ are inverse functions

Please do not give away the answer but guide me in the right direction.

Many thanks and stay safe!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first part, it wants you to treat $y$ as a constant. For instance, if $y=2$, you would need to find the maximum of the function $2x-2x^4$ with respect to $x$. Finding the maximum for general $y$ gives you a function $G(y)$ such that $yG(y)-2(G(y))^4\geq yx-2x^4$ for any $x$.

As an example, if you wanted to find the maximum of $x-yx^2$ with respect to $x$, you would first find where the derivative is $0$, so
$$0=\frac{d}{dx}x-yx^2=1-2yx$$
Solving for $x$, you get the function $\frac{1}{2y}$, which is what they mean by $G(y)$ in the problem (you still need to verify this is actually a maximum of course).

The second part is worded a little strangely, but I think they want you to verify that the inverse function of $G$ is equal to the derivative of $2x^4$, although I’m not sure why they would ask for this without more context, so I might be misreading it.